# Is there a way in MATLAB to a find pattern in a file, where the search string is stored in another file ?

Tags: regex, matlab, pattern-matching

I have a pattern file say MyPatternFile.txt which has the following content

```
 A quick brown
 fox jumps over
 a lazy dog
```

My pattern searching file looks as below MyPatternSearchFile.txt

```
Text to be ignored
Text to be ignored
Text to be ignored
A quick brown
fox jumps over
a lazy dog
Text to be ignored
Text to be ignored
Text to be ignored
```

I have tried using the textscan command but didnt help me as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the `MyPatternFile.txt`

Search each line of this on each line from `MyPatternSearchFile.txt`

using **[`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)**

It returns a empty matrix if pattern is not found, use **[`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html)** for this check

Comment: I tried the following as per your suggestion:
str = importdata('MyPatternSearchFile.txt');
pat = importdata('MyPattern.txt');
strfind(str,pat);

It throws an error expecting the pat variable to be of char.

Comment: @MATLABnewbie ah not like that, refer the examples, read files line by line and scan accordingly.